# how to translate plain javascript in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i "translate" this code below in jquery?

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/height/ Try out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery the code will become

```
function openNav() {
  $("#myNav").height("100%");
}

function closeNav() {
  $("myNav").height("0%");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery, you can use the [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) function.

The first value you declare the CSS rule and with the second, the value.

```
function openNav() {
  $("#myNav").css('height', '100%');
}

function closeNav() {
  $("#myNav").css('height', '0%');
}
```

Or you can use jQueries [height()](https://api.jquery.com/height) function instead.

```
function openNav() {
  $("#myNav").height(100+'%');
}

function closeNav() {
  $("#myNav").height(0);
}
```

Comment: `.height()` is shorter.

Comment: @chade_ Added to my post.

Answer (score 1):

this is quite easy to achieve:

```
function openNav() {
  $("#myNav").css("height",  "100%");
}

function closeNav() {
  $("#myNav").css("height", "0%");
}
```

greetings

Answer (score 1):

The native `document.getElementById("myNav")` gets `$("#myNav")`. This is called [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).
The native `.style.height = "100%"` can easily be set with the [jQuery method `.height()`.](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Your code in jQuery would look like thio

```
function openNav() {
    $("#myNav").height("100%")
}

function closeNav() {
    $("#myNav").height("0%");
}
```

Comment: `$("#myNav").height(100)` will set 100px to the div. Not 100%

Answer (score 0):

A simple glance at the [jQuery height Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/) shows you can pass the height value to the height method.

```
$('#myNav').height(50);
```

You can also call the css() method to have a more granular control over the css properties. [jQuery css Documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/css/)